# Both headphones play same mixed/mono audio only on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, audio-jack

Having problems with audio. My sistem is with Ubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04) / Windows 7 dualboot.

- Ubuntu

I do not have any special drivers installed, just alsa stuff and pulseaudio. The loudspeakers work fine (on test screen 'right' button plays only from right channel and 'left' button plays only from left channel), however with the headphones I get everything from both channels.

- Windows

Both headphones and loudspeakers work perfectly fine. I have Realtek HD Audio Manager installed there.

Upon request I can supply further information.

Edit: Somewhere else I heard this could be helpful - I ran alsa-info.sh which is available [from here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/craftyjon/902247/raw/ee5d9d88e0a83df46850e0c696eac9066a98dd18/alsa-info.sh) and the result is available:

http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=181078b7e33688e7d943db55a0d68d59d270449f

Best,